# How can i make this code run asynchronously without using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

```
const delayFunction = async () => {
  const startTime = new Date().getTime();

  const duration = 10000; 

  console.log('START')
  while (new Date().getTime() - startTime < duration) {
   // this loop runs for 10 seconds
  }
  console.log('STOP');
};

const starterFunction = async () => {
  console.log('1');
  delayFunction();
  console.log('2');
  return 'DONE'
};

console.log(starterFunction())
```

so now I want an output as below:

1

2

DONE

START

STOP

If anyone knows how to achieve this with asynchronous programming please help me with this.

I tried creating a new promise and tried to execute the code inside it but even that dosent seem to be working.

```
const delayFunction = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
     const startTime = new Date().getTime();

     const duration = 10000; 

     console.log('START')
     while (new Date().getTime() - startTime < duration) {
     // this loop runs for 10 seconds
     }
     resolve(console.log('STOP'));
  });
};
```

Comment: You cannot make synchronous code (like that busy waiting loop) asynchronous. Wrapping it inside `new Promise` achieves nothing. You can only make code asynchronous by using the asynchronous primitives provided by the environment, such as `setTimeout` (if your goal is to delay something).

Comment: Yes I think there is no other way to make it asynchronous without using setTimeout

Comment: Yes, there is no way (see the first linked question). Why do you want to avoid `setTimeout`? What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Answer (score 0):

```
  const duration = 10000;

  console.log('START');

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('STOP');
      resolve();
    }, duration);
  });
};

const starterFunction = async () => {
  console.log('1');
  console.log('2');
  await delayFunction();
  return 'DONE';
};

(async () => {
  await starterFunction();
})();
```